# Unable to correctly parse URLs using Django template language

Tags: django, django-templates

I currently am trying to link a researcher's name if they provided a link, otherwise if they provide a blank input or N/A, then I choose not to link their name. I use the information from the researcher object using Django's template language, but when I check the result it ends up linking all of them, and those without input just have href = "" which links back to the homepage.

I've tried using {{r.website_link|length}} instead, but that just creates errors and the page won't load. I'm a newbie to frontend so I'm not sure if my "if" statement is incorrect or if my HTML logic is incorrect.

```html
<div>
  {% for r in researcher %}
    <div class="researcher">
    {% if "{{r.website_link}}" != "N/A" and "{{r.website_link}}" != "" %}
    <p><a class="researcherwebname" href="{{ r.website_link }}">{{ r.fullname|title}}</a> | {{ r.institution }} | {{r.position}} | <i>{{ r.des|capfirst }}</i></p>
    {% else %}
    <p> {{ r.fullname|title}} | {{ r.institution }} | {{r.position}} | <i>{{ r.des|capfirst }}</i></p>
    {% endif %} 

    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I expect it to link researchers with an actual r.website_link input, otherwise the name should be unlinked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
{% if r.website_link %}
    {% if r.website_link != "N/A" %}
        {# display researcher #}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: doing that (removing the "" around the object) causes an error: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '{{r.website_link}}' from '{{r.website_link}}'.

Comment: But that wasn't what Ben your you to do. He told you to remove the `{{` and `}}`, which is the correct answer.

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT! Thank you so much. If y'all have time, could someone explain to me why/when I use {{ }}? From what I understand, I use {{}} when encountering variables and using their attributes, which is why I did what I did.